# Form data is always empty no matter what we appended to it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, form-data

I'm trying to build a form data to send files alongside data to the back-end
so I have all my values stored in something like this

```
const [values, setValues] = useState ({
  name: '',
  profileImg: '',
  gallery: [] `it's an array of imgs`
});
```

and here is my attempts to convert this into formData

```
const tempPayload = new FormData();
tempPayload.append('name', values.name);
tempPayload.append('profileImg', values.profileImg)
for(let i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++){
tempPayload.append('gallery', gallery[i]
}
```

and when I try to console.log(tempPayload)
it's always empty?!
I expect it to have the data that I passed to it

Comment: Where do you use `setValues`?

Comment: Inside a child component

Answer (score -1):

You have to re assign the formData variable like this:

```
tempPayload = tempPayload.append('name', values.name);
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work, escially with TS, 

here is what I have tried: 
let tempPayload = new FormData(); 
tempPayload = tempPayload.append('something', someValue) as unknown as FormData;

Comment: FromData.append returns nothing, that's why it doesn't work this way